# Jackson and deserialisation when you don't know the JSON tag name ahead of time?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to use Jackson to deserialise my JSON, from Jira, into a set of POJOs. I have most of what I want working beautifully, now I just have to decode the custom field values.

My input JSON looks like:

```
{
  "expand": "renderedFields,names,schema,operations,editmeta,changelog,versionedRepresentations",
  "id": "104144",
  "self": "https://jira.internal.net/rest/api/2/issue/104144",
  "key": "PRJ-524",
  "fields": {
    "summary": "Redo unit tests to load from existing project",
    "components": [],
    "customfield_10240": {
      "self": "https://jira.internal.net/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10158",
      "value": "Normal",
      "id": "10158"
    }
}
```

I can trivially load the summary and components, since I know ahead of time what the name of those JSON elements are, and can define them in my POJO:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "expand", "self", "id", })
public class JiraJson
{
  private JiraFields fields;
  private String key;

  public JiraFields getFields()
  {
    return fields;
  }

  public String getKey()
  {
    return key;
  }

  public void setFields(JiraFields newFields)
  {
    fields = newFields;
  }

  public void setKey(String newKey)
  {
    key = newKey;
  }
}
```

And similarly for `JiraFields`:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "issuetype", "priority", "status" })
public class JiraFields
{
  private List<JiraComponent> components;
  private String summary;

  public List<JiraComponent> getComponents()
  {
    return components;
  }

  public String getSummary()
  {
    return summary;
  }

  public void setComponents(List<JiraComponent> newComponents)
  {
    components = newComponents;
  }

  public void setSummary(String newSummary)
  {
    summary = newSummary;
  }
}
```

However, the field `custom_10240` actually differs depending on which Jira system this is run against, on one it is `custom_10240`, on another it is `custom_10345`, so I cannot hard-code this into the POJO. Using another call, it is possible to know at runtime, before the deserialisation starts, what the name of the field is, but this is not possible at compile time.

Assuming that I want to map the `value` field into a `String` on `JiraFields` called `Importance`, how do I go about doing that? Or perhaps simpler, how to map this `Importance` onto a `JiraCustomField` class?

Comment: JIRA ships a REST client with objects already defined. Have you looked into using that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching further, I finally found the [JsonAlias annotation](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAlias.html). This is still defined at compile time, but I had something that I could search further on!

Further searching, and I found [PropertyNamingStrategy](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.html), which allows you to rename what JSON field name is expected for a setter/field. This has the advantage in that this is done via a method, and the class can be constructed at runtime.

Here is the class that I used to perform this mapping:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MapperConfig;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedField;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMethod;

public final class CustomFieldNamingStrategy
  extends PropertyNamingStrategy
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 8263960285216239177L;
  private final Map<String, String> fieldRemapping;
  private final Map<String, String> reverseRemapping;

  public CustomFieldNamingStrategy(Map<String, String> newFieldRemappings)
  {
    fieldRemapping = newFieldRemappings;
    reverseRemapping = fieldRemapping.entrySet()//
                                     .stream()//
                                     .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue,
                                                               Map.Entry::getKey));
  }

  @Override
  public String nameForField(MapperConfig<?> config, AnnotatedField field, String defaultName)
  {
    if (field.getDeclaringClass().getName().equals(JiraFields.class.getName()))
    {
      return reverseRemapping.getOrDefault(defaultName, defaultName);
    }
    return defaultName;
  }

  @Override
  public String nameForSetterMethod(MapperConfig<?> config, AnnotatedMethod method,
                                    String defaultName)
  {
    if (method.getDeclaringClass().getName().equals(JiraFields.class.getName()))
    {
      return reverseRemapping.getOrDefault(defaultName, defaultName);
    }
    return defaultName;
  }

  @Override
  public String nameForGetterMethod(MapperConfig<?> config, AnnotatedMethod method,
                                    String defaultName)
  {
    if (method.getDeclaringClass().getName().equals(JiraFields.class.getName()))
    {
      return reverseRemapping.getOrDefault(defaultName, defaultName);
    }
    return defaultName;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a method annotated with [`@JsonAnySetter`](https://www.concretepage.com/jackson-api/jackson-jsonanygetter-and-jsonanysetter-example) that accepts all properties that are undefined (and not ignored).  in case of a Json Object (like the custom field in the question) Jackson passes a `Map` that contains all the Object properties (it may even contain `Map` values in case of nested objects).  You can now at run time extract whatever properties you want:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "issuetype", "priority", "status" })
public class JiraFields
{
    private List<JiraComponent> components;
    private String summary;
    private String importance;

    // getter/setter omitted for brevity

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setCustomField(String name, Object value) {
        System.out.println(name);  // will print "customfield_10240"
        if (value instanceof Map) {  // just to make sure we got a Json Object
            Map<String, Object> customfieldMap = (Map<String, Object>)value;
            if (customfieldMap.containsKey("value")) {  // check if object contains "value" property
                setImportance(customfieldMap.get("value").toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer @SharonBenAsher, my issue is that the real XML has several of these custom fields. Is there any way that I can pass state into the deserialiser, or do I just have to deal with global statics to get the information that I need?

Comment: Why do you say XML? the question specifies JSON? all custom fields will go to the same `setCustomField()` and you can interogate the arguments and extract whatever info you wish

Comment: Mental slip-up… this is JSON, not XML. The issue is that if I need to read the mapping from name → fieldName from global statics, then I can only talk to one Jira system at a time, and I need to introduce serialisation around that. Ideally I would be able to set something on the ObjectMapper which I could use to remap `customfield_10240` → `importance`, then the state would be local, and I don't need to worry about the threading issues.